# How do I handle errors in an f-string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, f-string

I am attempting to handle errors within an f-string, but my attempts don't seem to work. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
string = f"For example I thought this syntax would work but it doesn't {try: 5/0 except Exception: str(infinity)}"
```

Comment: ["Beautiful is better than ugly", "simple is better than complex", and "readability counts"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Even if you _could_ do this, you _shouldn't_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. Move the exception handling out of the f-string.

Comment: Judging from your points I guess you are the final arbiter. Sad, but fair.

Comment: How would you suggest that I take it out of the f-string?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to process whatever you need before composing the fstring and store as a variable, then you could reference the variable in the fstring as below:

```
from math import inf

try:
    div_by_zero = 5/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    div_by_zero = str(inf)

my_string = f"Processed outside: {div_by_zero}"
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.